# What SQLite column name can be/cannot be?

Tags: sql, sqlite, keyword

Is there any rule for the SQLite's column name?

- Can it have characters like '/'?
- Can it be UTF-8?

Answer (score 21):

> Can it have characters like '/'?

All examples are from SQlite 3.5.9 running on Linux.

If you surround the column name in double quotes, you can:

```
> CREATE TABLE test_forward ( /test_column INTEGER );
SQL error: near "/": syntax error
> CREATE TABLE test_forward ("/test_column" INTEGER );
> INSERT INTO test_forward("/test_column") VALUES (1);
> SELECT test_forward."/test_column" from test_forward;
1
```

That said, **you probably shouldn't do this**.

Comment: You can, but it will be a PITA for the rest of the life of the database. I would strongly recommend not doing it.

Comment: @Brian Hooper - I agree, but it actually sounds like putting single/double quotes is a good practice after reading http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html.  I rarely see this in real-world queries, though.

Comment: I avoid using reserved words as table and column names. This can cause problems during migration and similar activities, but the number of reserved words isn't really very large and they can be avoided with a little thought. I prefer that to having to worry about those little ticks for the rest of my employment. But some code generators supply them automatically so it may not be an issue if you're using one of them.

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals.  Double quotes are for identifiers.  Single quotes work here because SQLite is liberal in what it accepts, but it's non-standard.

Comment: Seconding dan04's comment.  Column names like "16" will result in a literal comparison in a where statement if surrounded by single quotes or not surrounded at all.  Only double quotes result in the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 13):

The following answer is based on the SQLite source code, mostly relying on the file `parse.y` (input for the lemon parser).

### TL;DR:

The allowed series of characters for column and table names in `CREATE TABLE` statements are

- `'`-escaped strings of any kind (even keywords)
- Identifiers, which means

  - ``` and `"`-escaped strings of any kind (even keywords)
  - a series of the `MSB=1` 8-bit ASCII characters or 7-bit ASCII characters with `1` in the following table that **doesn't form a keyword**:
    [image: Valid identifier characters]
- Keyword `INDEXED` because it's non-standard
- Keyword `JOIN` for reason that is unknown to me.

The allowed series of characters for result columns in a `SELECT` statement are

- Either a string or an identifier as described above
- All of the above if used as a column alias written after `AS`

### Now to the exploration process itself

1. let's look at the syntax for `CREATE TABLE` columns

   ```
   // The name of a column or table can be any of the following:
   //
   %type nm {Token}
   nm(A) ::= id(X).         {A = X;}
   nm(A) ::= STRING(X).     {A = X;}
   nm(A) ::= JOIN_KW(X).    {A = X;}
   ```
2. digging deeper, we find out that

   ```
   // An IDENTIFIER can be a generic identifier, or one of several
   // keywords.  Any non-standard keyword can also be an identifier.
   //
   %type id {Token}
   id(A) ::= ID(X).         {A = X;}
   id(A) ::= INDEXED(X).    {A = X;}
   ```

   "Generic identifier" sounds unfamiliar. A quick look into `tokenize.c` however brings forth the definition

   ```
   /*
   ** The sqlite3KeywordCode function looks up an identifier to determine if
   ** it is a keyword.  If it is a keyword, the token code of that keyword is 
   ** returned.  If the input is not a keyword, TK_ID is returned.
   */

   /*
   ** If X is a character that can be used in an identifier then
   ** IdChar(X) will be true.  Otherwise it is false.
   **
   ** For ASCII, any character with the high-order bit set is
   ** allowed in an identifier.  For 7-bit characters, 
   ** sqlite3IsIdChar[X] must be 1.
   **
   ** Ticket #1066.  the SQL standard does not allow '$' in the
   ** middle of identfiers.  But many SQL implementations do. 
   ** SQLite will allow '$' in identifiers for compatibility.
   ** But the feature is undocumented.
   */
   ```

   For a full map of identifier characters, please consult the `tokenize.c`.
3. It is still unclear what are the available names for a `result-column` (i. e. the column name or alias assigned in the `SELECT` statement). `parse.y` is again helpful here.

   ```
   // An option "AS <id>" phrase that can follow one of the expressions that
   // define the result set, or one of the tables in the FROM clause.
   //
   %type as {Token}
   as(X) ::= AS nm(Y).    {X = Y;}
   as(X) ::= ids(Y).      {X = Y;}
   as(X) ::= .            {X.n = 0;}
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Except for placing "illegal" identifier names between double quotes `"identifier#1"`, `[` before and `]` after works as well `[identifire#2]`.

Example:

```
sqlite> create table a0.tt ([id#1] integer primary key, [id#2] text) without rowid;
sqlite> insert into tt values (1,'test for [x] id''s');
sqlite> select * from tt
   ...> ;
id#1|id#2
1|test for [x] id's
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer but may help - these are the keywords from https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html converted to an array.

```
["ABORT", "ACTION", "ADD", "AFTER", "ALL", "ALTER", "ALWAYS", "ANALYZE", "AND", "AS", 
"ASC", "ATTACH", "AUTOINCREMENT", "BEFORE", "BEGIN", "BETWEEN", "BY", "CASCADE", "CASE", "CAST", 
"CHECK", "COLLATE", "COLUMN", "COMMIT", "CONFLICT", "CONSTRAINT", "CREATE", "CROSS", "CURRENT", "CURRENT_DATE", 
"CURRENT_TIME", "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", "DATABASE", "DEFAULT", "DEFERRABLE", "DEFERRED", "DELETE", "DESC", "DETACH", "DISTINCT", 
"DO", "DROP", "EACH", "ELSE", "END", "ESCAPE", "EXCEPT", "EXCLUDE", "EXCLUSIVE", "EXISTS", 
"EXPLAIN", "FAIL", "FILTER", "FIRST", "FOLLOWING", "FOR", "FOREIGN", "FROM", "FULL", "GENERATED", 
"GLOB", "GROUP", "GROUPS", "HAVING", "IF", "IGNORE", "IMMEDIATE", "IN", "INDEX", "INDEXED", 
"INITIALLY", "INNER", "INSERT", "INSTEAD", "INTERSECT", "INTO", "IS", "ISNULL", "JOIN", "KEY", 
"LAST", "LEFT", "LIKE", "LIMIT", "MATCH", "MATERIALIZED", "NATURAL", "NO", "NOT", "NOTHING", 
"NOTNULL", "NULL", "NULLS", "OF", "OFFSET", "ON", "OR", "ORDER", "OTHERS", "OUTER", 
"OVER", "PARTITION", "PLAN", "PRAGMA", "PRECEDING", "PRIMARY", "QUERY", "RAISE", "RANGE", "RECURSIVE", 
"REFERENCES", "REGEXP", "REINDEX", "RELEASE", "RENAME", "REPLACE", "RESTRICT", "RETURNING", "RIGHT", "ROLLBACK", 
"ROW", "ROWS", "SAVEPOINT", "SELECT", "SET", "TABLE", "TEMP", "TEMPORARY", "THEN", "TIES", 
"TO", "TRANSACTION", "TRIGGER", "UNBOUNDED", "UNION", "UNIQUE", "UPDATE", "USING", "VACUUM", "VALUES", 
"VIEW", "VIRTUAL", "WHEN", "WHERE", "WINDOW", "WITH", "WITHOUT"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Valid field names are subject to the same rules as valid Table names. Checked this with SQlite administrator.

1. Only Alphanumeric characters and underline are allowed
2. The field name must begin with an alpha character or underline

Stick to these and no escaping is needed and it may avoid future problems.

Comment: -1; [J Polfer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3373549/1709587) on this very page clearly demonstrates that your claim that *"Only Alphanumeric characters and underline are allowed"* is not correct. Also, *"Checked this with SQlite administrator"* isn't exactly a confidence-inspiring source of information.