# android SQLite exception near "/"

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

When I run my code,
 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error..

Why it doesn't work?
Thankyou all in advance..
Here is my helper class

```
public class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "Restaurant";
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT1 = "Restaurant name";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT2 = "Ac/non ac";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT3 = "Total chairs";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT4 = "Reserved chairs";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT5 = "Date";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT6 = "fromTime"; 
public static final String KEY_CONTENT7 = "toTime"; 
public static final String KEY_CONTENT8 = "Name";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT9 = "Contact Number";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT10 = "Table id";


private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
      "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
      + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
      + KEY_CONTENT1 + " text not null, "
      + KEY_CONTENT2 + " text not null, "
      + KEY_CONTENT3 + " integer not null, "
      + KEY_CONTENT4 + " integer not null, "
      + KEY_CONTENT5 + " text not null, "
      + KEY_CONTENT6 + " text not null, "
      + KEY_CONTENT7 + " text not null, "
      + KEY_CONTENT8 + " text not null, "
      + KEY_CONTENT9 + " text not null, "
      + KEY_CONTENT10 + " text not null) ";


public Helper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: check this `KEY_CONTENT2 = "Ac/non ac"`

Comment: I am not really sure but I think it is not allowed to use "spaces" and "special chars" like "/" in column names...

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373234/what-sqlite-column-name-can-be-cannot-be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table and column names in SQLite cannot have `/` in them, and you're trying to call a column `Ac/non ac`.

The support for special characters in table and column names in SQLite is a bit sketchy overall, so I'd also recommend using replacing your spaces in the column names with `_`. The alternative is to enclose them in quotes, but that may/may not work depending on SQLite version.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming KEY_CONTENT2 to something not having '/' in it. I think '/'s are unacceptable in the names. And also remove all the spaces from the names.

Answer (score 0):

Or replace it with its unicode. U+002F