# SQLite: Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to execute this statement in `onUpgrade` method of database helper but I'm getting an error:

```
 database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE VEHICLE_HOURS(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "MINUTES INTEGER, VEHICLE VARCHAR(255), ORDER INTEGER);");
```

**ERROR**

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ORDER":
>   syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE
>   VEHICLE_HOURS(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, MINUTES INTEGER,
>   VEHICLE VARCHAR(255), ORDER INTEGER);

Thanks.

Comment: `order` is a reserved word in SQL.  Even if allowed, you should not sue it for a column name.

Comment: Order is a reserved word. "Order by", remember?

Comment: God... it's true. I knew it was a nonsense.. Thank you guys

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What SQLite column name can be/cannot be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373234/what-sqlite-column-name-can-be-cannot-be)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ORDER` is a reserved word in SQL. You could of course suppress that error by taking the name into quotes, like:

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE VEHICLE_HOURS(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        "MINUTES INTEGER, VEHICLE VARCHAR(255), \"ORDER\" INTEGER);");
```

but better just pick another column name, then nobody (including your future self) will hate you while maintaining this code.

Comment: Got caught in this, I was trying to do the same & failed.  Changed the table name & it worked.